# Invoking a plot method in Point Collection class

Tags: c#, charts, plot, delegates, invoke

I'm trying plot the DATA using a window form, by invoking delegate, I successfully plotted XY graph by using a button to fire/initiate the event (See code below).

I don't understand why my code works for plotting XY points but it doesn't work when I just want to plot Y points solely.

What i mean by plotting Y solely is i.e. X = 0 , 1, ,2, 3, 4, incrementing by 1 or in general any fixed increment , can be 0.1 or 0.01 , or anything. but the Y is passed in  by the user.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace PlottingSomeData
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Delegate
        private delegate int PlotXYDelegate(double x, double y);

        // parameter Chart, Series of the chart, x,y values of the graph
        private void PlotXYAppend(Chart chart, Series dataSeries, double x, double y) 
        {
            // invoke the delegate by passing in the add points method in point collection object
            chart.Invoke(new PlotXYDelegate(dataSeries.Points.AddXY), new Object[] { x, y });
        } 

        double[] X = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        double[] Y = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < X.Length || i < Y.Length; i++)
            {
                PlotXYAppend(this.chart2, this.chart2.Series[0], X[i], Y[i]);
            }
        }

        //UP to this line... the code below doesn't work.
        private delegate int PlotYDelegate(double x, double y);

        private void PlotYAppend(Chart chart, Series dataSeries, double y)
        {
            // I do the same here but it fails... for adding single Y value. 
            // There is error for the invoking line. I don't really know what the problem is.
            chart.Invoke(new PlotYDelegate(dataSeries.Points.AddY), new Object[] { y });
        } 
    }
}
```

Error: No overload for 'AddY' matches delegate 'PlotSomeData.Form1.PlotYDelegate
Sorry to get the program to work, you need to add the button and also get the chart from the toolbox .

Comment: What are the error details on the Invoke line?

Comment: No overload for 'AddY' matches delegate 'PlotSomeData.Form1.PlotYDelegate.

Comment: Um, AddY has two overloads but your delegate matches neither. Why do you have the double x param???